# Return only not matched Ids - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two objects, arr1 and arr2. arr1 is coming from database, while arr2 will be imported. While importing arr2, display those Ids not matched with arr1.

```
var arr1 = [
  {
    "department": "acdc",
    "employeeId": "10100999"
  },
  {
    "department": "asds",
    "employeeId": "10103227"
  },
  {
    "department": "dsds",
    "employeeId": "10103509"
  },
  ...... 1000 entries.
]
```

```
var arr2 = 
[
  {
    "department": "acdc",
    "employeeId": "101"
  },
  {
    "department": "asds",
    "employeeId": "1010"
  },
  {
    "department": "dsds",
    "employeeId": "10103509"
  }
]
```

Dispaly

> "No records found for Ids 101, 1010".

What I tried.

```
        var array1 = app.arr2.filter(function (entry1) {
            return arr1.some(function (entry2) {
                return entry1.employeeId != entry2.employeeId;
            });
        });
       console.log("no records found for Ids =", array1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to it. Just store the missing `employeeId`s to an array and then print it.

```js
var arr1=[{department:"acdc",employeeId:"10100999"},{department:"asds",employeeId:"10103227"},{department:"dsds",employeeId:"10103509"}];
var arr2=[{department:"acdc",employeeId:"101"},{department:"asds",employeeId:"1010"},{department:"dsds",employeeId:"10103509"}];

const missing = [];
arr2.forEach(item => {
  const exists = arr1.find(x => x.employeeId === item.employeeId);
  
  if (!exists) missing.push(item.employeeId);
});

console.log("no records found for Ids = " + missing.join(', '));
```

Answer (score 3):

I also needed to do the same thing the following code worked for me:

```
let arrayWithDistinctIds= arr1.filter(
  o1 =>
    !arr2.find(
      o2=> +o1.employeeId=== +o2.employeeId,
    ),
);
console.log('Array of objects whose ids are not equal',
arrayWithDistinctIds)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const items = arr2.filter((item) => {
 const record = arr1.find((temp) => temp.employeeId === item.employeeId);
 if(!record){
   return item;
 }
});

console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let notFound = [];
app.arr2.forEach(entry1 => {
    let missing = arr1.filter(entry2 => {
        return entry2.employeeId != entry1.employeeId;
    })
    if(missing.length == 0){
        notFound.push(entry1.employeeId)
    }
})
console.log(`no records found for Ids = ${notFound.join(', ')}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you actually trying to achieve? Return all elements from `arr2` which don't have a matching id in `arr1`?

```js
const arr1 = [1,2,3]
const arr2 = [2,3,4]

function matches(x, y) {
  return x === y; // add your matching function here
}

const arr = arr2.filter(x => !arr1.find(y => matches(x,y)));

console.log(arr);
```

This returns all elements from `arr2` which cannot be found in `arr1` according to the defined matching function